# html javascript search not working

Tags: javascript, html, search

This is the code :

```
<style>
.copyrighttoolbox {
  font-size:9px
}
</style>
<script>
function searchFor(searchEngine,searchQuery){
  for (var i = 0; i < searchEngine.length; i++) {
    if (searchEngine[i].type === 'radio' && searchEngine[i].checked) {
      value = searchEngine[i].value;   
    }
  }
  if (value=="google"){
    var x="http://google.com.hk/search?q="+searchQuery;
    window.location.href=x
  }
  if (value=="yahoo"){
    var x="http://hk.search.yahoo.com/search?p="+searchQuery;
    window.location.href=x
  }
  if (value=="bing"){
    var x="http://bing.com/search?q="+searchQuery;
    window.location.href=x
  }
  if (value=="wikipedia"){
    var x="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search="+searchQuery;
    window.location.href=x
  }
}
</script>
<form style="border:3px #cccccc dashed;width:400px">
  <select name="searchLoc">
    <option value="google">Google</option>
    <option value="yahoo">Yahoo</option>
    <option value="bing">Bing</option>
    <option value="wikipedia">Wikipedia</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="searchContent">
  <input type="submit" onclick="searchFor(this.form.searchLoc.value,this.form.searchContent.value);return false;" value="Search"><span class="copyrighttoolbox">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;by tool-box.weebly.com</p>
</form>
```

This is not working and the link after submit became:

> http://tool-box.weebly.com/web-tool.html?searchLoc=google&searchContent=search

How can I solve this problem?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is it that you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It looks like you are mixing up some things as the right value is already in the `searchEngine` variable.

```
function searchFor(searchEngine,searchQuery){
  if (searchEngine=="google"){
    var x="http://google.com.hk/search?q="+searchQuery;
    window.location.href=x
  }
  if (searchEngine=="yahoo"){
    var x="http://hk.search.yahoo.com/search?p="+searchQuery;
    window.location.href=x
  }
  if (searchEngine=="bing"){
    var x="http://bing.com/search?q="+searchQuery;
    window.location.href=x
  }
  if (searchEngine=="wikipedia"){
    var x="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search="+searchQuery;
    window.location.href=x
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Demo: plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8HRJmGsdjrArEEVQwu6Q?p=preview)

**Description:**

- You were cycling through `searchEngine` instead of just using the value you are passing from the `onclick` of the submit button.
- I also changed this to a switch instead of multiple `if` statements because of the nature of this use case.
- Next i closed all your javascript lines with `;` since there were some that were missing it.
- Finally I declared the `var x` at the top of the function so you don't get duplicate variable declaration warnings.

**JS**

```
function searchFor(searchEngine,searchQuery){
  var x = "";

  switch(searchEngine)
  {
   case "google":
    x="http://google.com.hk/search?q="+searchQuery;
    alert(x);
    window.location.href=x;
    break;
  case "yahoo":
    x="http://hk.search.yahoo.com/search?p="+searchQuery;
    window.location.href=x;
    break;
  case "bing":
    x="http://bing.com/search?q="+searchQuery;
    window.location.href=x;
    break;
  case "wikipedia":
    x="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search="+searchQuery;
    window.location.href=x;
    break;
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form style="border:3px #cccccc dashed;width:400px">
      <select name="searchLoc">
        <option value="google">Google</option>
        <option value="yahoo">Yahoo</option>
        <option value="bing">Bing</option>
        <option value="wikipedia">Wikipedia</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" name="searchContent">
      <input type="submit" onclick="javascript:searchFor(this.form.searchLoc.value,this.form.searchContent.value);return false;" value="Search"><span class="copyrighttoolbox">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;by tool-box.weebly.com</p>
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
.copyrighttoolbox {
    font-size:9px
}
```

Comment: what's this? `<script src="script.js"></script>`

Comment: @Jamie plunker separates the `js`, `html`, and `css` so you don't have it all in the `html` that's why it is including it.  If you open the plunker you'll see that.  You can just put it all back in one file if you prefer but separating it allows other items to use this same `js`.